# JMeter - How to extract and pass the name of a transaction controller into an HTTP header manager?

Tags: jmeter

Assume my test plan has a transaction controller (that has a few requests) and a HTTP header manager under it. I wanted to extract the name of transaction controller and pass it on to a value in HTTP header manager. Please suggest a way if we can do it, otherwise a workaround would help. Thanks.

Comment: You should I assume ? You provide the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the code that you are having problems with, then only we can assume something. You should also read How to Ask- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the Parent Controller from a Post Processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38049627/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-parent-controller-from-a-post-processor)